# Unique Constraint Failed: Authentication_authprofile.user_id, Anyone to help me

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, django-views

Am creating a user profile with custom model Fields. But am getting an error if l try to submit The form.
**UNIQUE constraint failed: Authentication_authprofile.user_id**

Am not seeing any error in my Code but anyone to help me and solve it.

**views.py**

```
def userprofile(request):
    url= request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        user_profile = AuthProfile()
        if AuthProfile.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).exists():
            avatar = request.POST.get('avatar')
            gender = request.POST.get('gender')
            country = request.POST.get('country')
            user_profile.avatar = avatar
            user_profile.gender = gender
            user_profile.country=country 
            user_profile.user_id=request.user.id
            user_profile.save()
            return redirect('/')
    return render(request, 'authentification/auth-policy/user-dashboard.html')
```

**Models.py**

```
class AuthProfile(models.Model):

    user= models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)

    avatar=models.ImageField(default='avatar.jpg',upload_to='profile_avatar')

    gender =models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

    country=models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:

        return f'{self.user.username}  Profile'

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)

    def create_auth_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

        if created:

            AuthProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)

    def save_auth_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):

        instance.authprofile.save()
```

l also attached a picture for error if I try to submit the form.

[[image]]

The problem is that l can't update the user profile.
anyone to help me

Comment: You create the `AuthProfile` through two paths: one through the signals and one through the view, hence the error. This is one - of the very many reasons - *not* to use signals. I don't know why people keep coming up with the exact same antipattern...

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating it, you are creating a new one. You should work with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


@login_required
def userprofile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_profile = get_object_or_404(AuthProfile, user=request.user)
        user_profile.avatar = request.POST['avatar']
        user_profile.gender = request.POST['gender']
        user_profile.country = request.POST['country']
        user_profile.save()
        return redirect('/')
    return render(request, 'authentification/auth-policy/user-dashboard.html')
```

---

> **Note**: Please use `request.POST['avatar']` over `request.POST.get('avatar')`. Using `.get(…)` often only silences the error, but not the problem: indeed it will work if the key is missing. But if the value for that key is really required, it will only result in more trouble later in the process.

---

> **Note**: It is better to use a [**`Form`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/)
> than to perform manual validation and cleaning of the data. A `Form` will not
> only simplify *rendering* a form in HTML, but it also makes it more convenient
> to *validate* the input, and *clean* the data to a more convenient type.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: Signals are often not a *robust* mechanism. I wrote [an article <sup>[Django-antipatterns]</sup>](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html) that discusses certain problems when using signals. Therefore you should use them only as a last resort.

Comment: But it returned an error **MultiValueDictKeyError** the error is directed to *Avatar* because for it has a default image when generating a new user profile when the user is created. How can l overcome it?

Comment: @Byansi: I would advise use a form. If `avatar` is an image, it will *never* be in `request.POST`, but in `request.FILES`.

Comment: :You mean no way of doing it without passing it forms.py

Comment: @Byansi: of course, with `request.FILES`, the reason to use forms is because validating and cleaning request data is cumbersome and can not be trusted, you don't have to *render* the form, but processing request data is typically done through a form, this will make it more reusable and will remove boilerplate code.

Comment: Your issue is good but am looking for the Way of doing it without interrupting the frontend layout, thats why l try find a way of doing it such way. What about **Class View** can't help me?

Comment: @Byansi: just define a form with the same field names at the Django side to process the request as the one you made at the frontend...

Comment: Try to show up to me because am not getting it, all the way l know with Django forms, frontend layout is interrupted.